# How to disable Previous and Next buttons in a Alexa Custom Skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm developing a radio skill for Alexa and would like to disable the next and previous buttons when the skill is appearing on an Echo Show device.
I've tested other radio skills and they have these buttons disabled.
I haven't found anything on [AudioPlayer Interface](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html) and [PlaybackControllers Interface](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/playback-controller-interface-reference.html) docs.
I'm using a radio.co stream. Take this as example: https://streams.radio.co/s931d44131/listen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those buttons can't be disabled.

But you can (and should) handle those kinds of requests too and return an empty response. We come to that issue with our project Convoworks and below is an empty response that we are using in such cases. Note that it ends the session, just as any other media related response.

```json
{
    "version" : "1.0",
    "response" : {
        "shouldEndSession" : true,
        "type" : "_DEFAULT_RESPONSE"
    },
}
```